# Error when create db:seed as interger in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to make the seed data in the form of a string and interger, but when I create an error "int" is not recognized

This's my code

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code directly rather than images of it. Same goes for the error messages... It is much more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP native function [rand()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_rand.asp) :

```
rand(1,999); // rand(min,max)
```

Or, use the [`mt_rand(min,max)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)  to make bigger integers :

```
mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:
use Illuminate\Support\Int;

or

'nip' => \Int::random(10);

Answer (score 0):

That is because there's no `Int` facade.

You can check in the helpers section of the docs, the only helper classes are `Arr` and `Str`.

What you could do, as the other answers recommend, is to use a native PHP function (like [`mt_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mt-rand.php)) to randomly generate integers:

```
$randomInteger = mt_rand($min = 0, $max = null);
```